# How to display records using group by names with date?

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

I am trying to display records using group by name but when the sdate is available.

my table :

[image]

Example

Hotel Tampa is available on jan 1, jan 4,jan 6
then I want to show like this

| name | available date |
| --- | --- |
| tampa | jan 1 , jan 2 , jan 6 |
| tabcd | jan 3 , jan 9 , jan 12 |

Comment: What's the query you are trying to use that isn't working?

Comment: i don't know how to grab column like this :

Comment: Right... but what queries have you tried so far that you thought might work but don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(sdate) as gr_date FROM table_name GROUP BY name
```

Comment: no i want to display all records i don't have any parameters just want to display records as i displayed using group by 

beacause lots of hotels are available in everyday